# Prove that for any $m, n \in\omega$ that (i) $m + 0 = m$, (ii) $m + n^+ = (m + n)^+$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals, recursion

I am getting repeatedly lost trying to approach this question:

Prove that for any  $m, n \in\omega$ that (i) $m + 0 = m$, (ii) $m + n^+ = (m + n)^+$

I can fairly well grasp the idea that the definition of the addition function is an application of the Recursion Theorem, but I am getting repeatedly stumped with regard to how to demonstrate it by way of a proof. Can anyone help? Even a hint would be most welcome at this stage! Thankyou

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on how you’ve defined addition of ordinals; you need to add that definition to the question.

Comment: This is what I am working with:                                      We define addition to be the function ω x ω → ω (where "ω" is the set of all natural numbers)                                         {<<x, y>, z> | x, y, z ∈ ω and z = $f_x$(y)}

Comment: And what function is $f_x$?

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I recite the Recursion Theorem I'm working from in full, which is as follows (thanks for your patience) -                                                    
"If we have a set A and an element z ∈ A and a function F : A → A then there is a unique function H : ω → A such that                                                       
(i) H (0) = z                                                      
(ii) H ($n^+$) = F (H(n))

Comment: We then define the function $f_k$ (add k for natural number k) to be                                                                $f_k$($n^+$) = $($f_k$(n))^+$

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments, for any $m\in\omega,$ you are *defining* $f_m:\omega\to\omega$ recursively by $f_m(0):=m,$ $f_m\left(n^+\right):=\bigl(f_m(n)\bigr)^+.$ Then you are *defining* $m+n:=f_m(n)$ for any $m,n\in\omega.$

The proof then follows directly from the definitions, since $m+0=f_m(0)=m,$ and $$m+n^+=f_m(n^+)=\bigl(f_m(n)\bigr)^+=(m+n)^+.$$